# Delete row if column2 value exists anywhere in column1

Tags: sql, exists

A program starts with a table like the one below:

```
ID   data1   data2   ...   copyID
15      a       b           NULL
16      c       d            11
```

You instruct the program to create new rows based off of information in existing rows. The copyID field holds the ID of the row in which data was copied from. After copying rows 1 and 2, the new table looks like the one below:

```
ID   data1   data2   ...   copyID
15      a       b            NULL
16      c       d             11
17      a       b             15
18      c       d             16
```

Now, I would like to only select rows that aren't "duplicates" of rows we are already capturing. Since ID 15 is "original," it should be maintained. Since there is no ID = 11, we want to maintain ID 16. Since we already have ID = 15 and ID = 16, we do not need ID = 17 or ID = 18. What is the process to handle this decision making in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the code below will resolve your issue:

```
select      a.*
from        yourtable a
left join   yourtable b
on          a.copid = b.id
where       b.id is null
```

Comment: The `a.copid is null` in the `where` clause is redundant. that's because if `a.copid` is null, then `b.id` is also null, and you have that specified already.

Comment: yes.., you're right (I was testing and forgot to remove.. thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS

For example:

```
declare  @T table (ID int, data1 varchar(30), data2 varchar(30), copyID int);

-- adding the parent records
insert into @T (ID, data1, data2, copyID) values
(15,'a','b',NULL),
(16,'c','d',11);

-- adding the duplicates
insert into @T (ID, copyID, data1, data2)
select m.maxID + row_number() over (order by id) as newID, t.ID as copyID, t.data1, t.data2
from @T t
cross apply (select max(id) as maxID from @T) m;

-- Only selecting those the parent record does not exist
select * 
from @T t1 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from @T t2
    where t1.copyID = t2.ID
    and t1.data1 = t2.data1 and t1.data2 = t2.data2
);

-- Or via a LEFT JOIN and keeping those that are only on the left side
select t1.* 
from @T t1
left join @T t2 on (t1.copyID = t2.ID and t1.data1 = t2.data1 and t1.data2 = t2.data2)
where t2.ID is null;
```

Returns:

```
ID data1 data2 copyID
15 a     b     NULL
16 c     d     11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.copyid is null or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.copyid);
```

This handles both the `NULL` case and the `NOT EXISTS` case.

This can be simplified to:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.copyid);
```